# Не могу включить беспроводной адаптер Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, powershell, wifi, windows-server, windows-server-2012

Не могу включить беспроводной адаптер ни через панель упр. ни через PowerShell.

ввожу команду :

```
PS C:\Users\Администратор> netsh interface show interface
```

выводит:

```
Состояние адм.  Состояние     Тип              Имя интерфейса
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Запрещен       Отключен       Выделенный       Wireless

Разрешен       Подключен      Выделенный       Ethernet
```

как видите `wireless` запрещен

```
Enable-NetAdapter -Name "Wireless" -Confirm:$false

netsh interface set interface "Wireless" enable
```

тоже не работает (не включает адаптер)

службу беспроводной сети в ролях и компонентах добавил

Comment: Пробовали что-либо типа "Add-WindowsFeature -Name Wireless-Networking" ? У нас уже нет 2012го, но что-то было связано с этим, даже при добавленной роли.

Comment: Add-WindowsFeature wireless-networking ? пробовал, затем запускал сервис net start wlansvc, результата тот же